# How come $\{ x \in A; \inf f_{n}(x) < t \}= \cup\{ x \in A;f_n(x) < t \}$ but not with $\le$

Tags: real-analysis

I been tying to figure out why

$\{ x \in A; \sup f_{n}(x) \le t \}= \bigcap_\limits{n\in\Bbb{N}}\{ x \in A;f_{n}(x) \le t \}$

and

$\{ x \in A; \inf f_{n}(x) < t \}= \bigcup_\limits{n\in\Bbb{N}}\{ x \in A;f_{n}(x) < t \}$

but not

$\{ x \in A; \sup f_{n}(x) < t \}= \bigcap_\limits{n\in\Bbb{N}}\{ x \in A;f_{n}(x) < t \}$

$\{ x \in A; \inf f_{n}(x) \le t \}= \bigcup_\limits{n\in\Bbb{N}}\{ x \in A;f_{n}(x) \le t \}$

Can someone help me shed light on this?

Update

I think I solved one, let $f_{\epsilon} =1-\epsilon$ be constant on some set then $\sup f_{\epsilon}=1$ but $f_{\epsilon}<1 , \forall \epsilon$ thats a counterexample at least, but "why" doesn't it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Take $f_n(x)=1-\dfrac{1}{xn}$, for all $x \in A=(0,1]$.

In this case, $\sup_\limits{n} \ f_n(x)=1 \Rightarrow \{ x \in A; \sup_\limits{n} f_{n}(x) < 1 \}= \emptyset$.  On the other hand, $\{ x \in A;f_{n}(x) < 1 \}=A$.

2) Take $f_n(x)=1+\dfrac{1}{xn}$, for all $x \in A=(0,1]$.

$\inf_\limits{n} \ f_n(x)=1 \Rightarrow \{ x \in A; \inf_\limits{n} f_{n}(x) \le 1 \}= A$. But, $\{ x \in A;f_{n}(x) \le 1 \}=\emptyset$.